# Рандомный знак (отрицательное или положительное) в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как поставить знак +/- в JavaScript. Хочу поставить в функцию типа `0 +/- Math.random()`, где +/- будет случайным знаком.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, где конкретно и зачем поставить? Что вы ожидаете от его установки?

Comment: @Kirill, Вас интересует знак(читай `символ`) или же оператор?..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Оператора `+/-` в JavaScript нет.

Если Вы хотите добиться такого поведения, при котором Ваше случайное число было еще и со случайным знаком, Вам придётся реализовать данное поведение самому.

Сделать это можно, умножая полученное число на `+1` или `-1`.
Добиться случайности можно с помощью всё той же функции `Math.random()`.
К примеру: 
когда  результат `Math.random()` будет меньше 0.5 - умножаем на `-1`
когда больше либо равно 0.5 - умножаем на `+1`

В итоге получаем слудующую конструкцию:

```
((Math.random() < 0.5) ? -1 : 1)*Math.random()
```

Где `((Math.random() < 0.5) ? -1 : 1)` - генерирует случайный знак.

Ниже приведён пример работы данной конструкции.
Мы генерируем 20 различных значений и добавляем их в список.

```js
for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.innerHTML = ((Math.random() < 0.5) ? -1 : 1)*Math.random();
    document.getElementById("test").appendChild(listItem);
}
```

```html
<ul id="test">
</ul>
```

**UPD1:**

Как справедливо заметил @Qwertiy, того же самого поведения можно добиться используя более лаконичную конструкцию:

```
(Math.random() - .5) * 2
```

Что здесь происходит?

Сначала мы из `Math.random()` вычитаем 0.5.
Что это нам даёт?
Интервал возвращаемых `Math.random()` значений включает значения от 0 до 1
Вычитая из результата 0.5, мы смещаем данный интервал до следующего: `[-0.5, 0.5)`.

Позже мы умножаем полученное число на 2 и интервал генерируемых значений содержит уже числа от `-1` до `+1`(не включительно), что идентично результату, которого мы достигаем с помощью первой конструкции.Только в первом случае значение `-1`, также не было включено в наш интервал.

Результат также можно посмотреть в аналогичном примере:

```js
    for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.innerHTML = (Math.random() - .5) * 2;
        document.getElementById("test").appendChild(listItem);
    }
```

```html
    <ul id="test">
    </ul>
```

Comment: `(Math.random() - .5) * 2`

Comment: @Qwertiy, Лаконичнее. Добавлю.

Comment: @Qwertiy, обновил ответ.

Comment: Только там `[-.5, .5)` получится, а не `[-.5, .5]`.

Comment: @Qwertiy , поправил

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, если речь идёт именно о задаче генерировать СЛУЧАЙНЫЙ знак +/-, то есть вариант без всяких условий, прямо отвечающий на поставленный вопрос :

```
private float[] znakArray = new float[] {-1f,1f};

int znak_i = Random.Range(0,znakArray.Length);
flout znak = znakArray[znak_i];
```